# Is ”sola scriptura” the first appeal of "Ecclesia Reformata, Semper Reformanda?"

Tags: reformed-theology, reformation

**"*Sola scriptura*"** & **"*Ecclesia Reformata, Semper Reformanda*"** (a church reformed and always to be reformed according to the Word of God)  are the "two mottos" among others, from the early church and the reformation era that bring us to the passionate fervor of the bygone days of the reformation.

- How relevant are the mottos to modern day churches, especially evangelical Protestant churches?
- Is the age-old "theological deadlock" over the dogmas, namely the Soteriology among the major  denominations,  from the theological laxity and inattention to the Scripture?